bin/cmake: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
there is an error when I build cmake:
bin/cmake: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
but libssl.so.10 is in /lib64 when I run command "find /lib64/* -name "libssl.so.10"
why？ and is there any solution？

